# How to add .gif file i background

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

1. I am using ubuntu
2. when I code fro background-img the same error in every project
3. not use any file like `.gif` `.jpg`

```
Error:   Failed to compile
./src/backimg.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/backimg.css)
Error: Can't resolve '/images/back.jpg' in '/home/sohail/panacloud-Projects/pro-4A web Animation/animation-app/src'
```

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

```js
import './backimg.css';

function App() {
  return <div className="App"><h1>
  Sohail</h1></div>;
}

export default App;
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* when i use image in background */
  background: url("/images/back.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css file change the path of images folder

try :

```
background: url("./images/back.jpg");
```

instead of

```
background: url("/images/back.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

before that, I get an image from the public folder therefore it's not got an image
know I create a folder in src folder and get image properly
But I can not understand what problem in a public folder does not work with backgrounimage